# How to provide flutter path in next User Account (2nd user) mac?

Tags: flutter, path

I have installed flutter and it's working but it doesn't work in another user. For another user I have given it as administration privilege. Do I need to download the flutter SDK again and setup or somehow I can access or give path in this 2nd user? I tried everything but it's not working.

Comment: what's the path in which you installed Flutter?

Comment: export PATH = "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH" . It's inside the .zshrc file

Comment: then you need to add this line to the .zshrc of the other user

Comment: I have already done that. But it's not working. When I type flutter in terminal, it say's no command found

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should do:

in your main account **(Admin)**

**In your flutter SDK Directory**

in my case : /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/

click with two finger **(double click)** on the file that contains the flutter SDK in my case it's caskroom then press get info [Should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt7d6.png),

**in sharing & permissions**

unlock the lock then press **+** and then add the second user and make it **read/write**

Comment: Also apply to all items in folder: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac

Comment: And you also need to update your path: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path